# link_text is empty when the scraped link content has HTML in it

Tags: python, scrapy

In a CrawlSpider, I use a LinkExtractor in which I assign a callback.

In the callback, I use the `response` variable in order to get the link informations, such as `response.url` and `response.status`. I also need to extract the content of the link, so I found it in the meta : `response.meta.get('link_text')`.

The problem I face with this method is that `link_text` returns an HTML free string. Here's an example :

`<a href="/page1">My link</a>`, link_text will return "My link", whereas `<a href="/page1"><svg><path/></svg> My link <span>...</span></a>`, link_text will return "" !

I don't mind it strips the HTML tags, but the fact that I can't extract the "My link" string is a problem for me.
Is there another way to achieve this?

Edit:

Here's my code.
As you can see, linktext returns "" when theres HTML inside a link.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class MyItem(Item):
    url = Field()
    status = Field()
    context = Field()
    link_text = Field()

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'creepy_crawler'
    target_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['https://example.com/']

    rules = [
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(allow_domains=target_domains),
            callback='parse_internal',
            follow=True
        )
    ]

    def parse_internal(self, response):
        referer = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
        if response.status != 200 and referer is not None:

            linktext = " ".join(response.meta.get('link_text').split())
            if linktext == "":
              linktext = "Must have html in it.."

            item = MyItem()
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['status'] = response.status
            item['context'] = referer
            item['link_text'] = linktext
            yield item
```

Comment: Could you share your spider so that we can take a look?

Comment: @Ryan, I added my code.

Comment: Please, consider reporting this upstream as a bug.